# P/Invoke Function Overloading

Tags: f#, pinvoke

I'm attempting to P/Invoke a C library from F#, and have encountered a peculiar issue. I have a module containing all my `extern` functions. The underlying C library has two functions with the same name, but different arguments. This, of course, is not allowed in an F# module.

```
module C =

  open System.Runtime.InteropServices

  [<DllImport("libc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
  extern int setValue(nativeint source, int value)

  [<DllImport("libc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
  extern int setValue(nativeint source, string value)

  // the previous function declaration cause the following compile-time error:
  // Duplicate definition of value 'setValue'
```

Is there some special way to work around this? I can not alter the C library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`EntryPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint.aspx) attribute should work (e.g. with an ordinal), if MSDN can be trusted (haven't tested in F#). Name your imported functions e.g. `setValueInt()` and `setValueString()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this whole P/Invoke scene.